# Добавить в callback_query_handler несколько текстов (telegram bot, aiogram)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

в callback_query_handler(text = ...)
Ситуация такая:
У меня есть кнопки:

```
GROUP1 = ['С-111', 'С-112', 'С-113', 'ЭГ-11', 'Э-121', 'МР-131', 'МР-132', 'К-141', 'М-151', 'АТ-181', 'РП-161',
          'Т-171', 'СВ-114']
GROUP2 = ['С-211', 'С-212', 'С-213', 'ЭГ-21', 'Э-221', 'МР-231', 'МР-232', 'МР-233', 'К-241', 'М-251', 'АТ-281',
          'РП-261', 'Т-271', 'ТГ-291', 'СВ-214']
GROUP3 = ['С-311', 'С-312', 'С-313', 'ЭГ-31', 'Э-321', 'К-341', 'МР-331', 'МР-332', 'МР-333', 'М-351', 'АТ-381',
          'Т-371', 'ТГ-391', 'СВ-314']
GROUP4 = ['С-411', 'Э-421', 'МР-431', 'К-441', 'А-461', 'М-451', 'Т-471', 'ТГ-491']

# --- Button for Groups ---

btnmenu1 = [InlineKeyboardButton(text = x, callback_data=x) for x in GROUP1]
btnmenu2 = [InlineKeyboardButton(text = x, callback_data=x) for x in GROUP2]
btnmenu3 = [InlineKeyboardButton(text = x, callback_data=x) for x in GROUP3]
btnmenu4 = [InlineKeyboardButton(text = x, callback_data=x) for x in GROUP4]
```

у меня есть код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text = 'С-111')
async def groups(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.delete()
    text = 'С-111'
    user = groups_info()[0]
    set_groups(user_id=user[0], groups=text)
    await call.message.answer('Группа выбрана успешно.')
```

который записывается в базу данных, в таблицу (groups, user_group)
Всего групп - 50.
Можно ли в этот callback handler добавить несколько групп?
т.е. - Чтобы в callback handler откликался не только на кнопку 'С-111' но и на другие, также, чтобы при нажатии определённой кнопки, в таблицу записывалась та группа, которая была нажата при кнопке.
Просто делать callback для каждой группы не очень, может кто-нибудь знает, как можно сделать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так. Просто в список забей

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=['С-111', 'c-123',...])
async def groups(call: CallbackQuery):
    text = call.data
```

Comment: в callback handler?

Comment: @JimmyJamJangles обновил

Comment: Благодарю, но у меня есть переменная ниже, тоже (text = ), в таблицу оно будет записывать только "С-111", как это можно исправить?

Comment: @JimmyJamJangles Снова обновил

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать lambda методы вместо text:

```
@dp.callback_query_habdler(lambda c: c.data in GROUP1)
async def groupsCallbackHandler(call: CallbackQuery):
    pass
```